# How to send file to a particular user in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, socket.io

I am creating a Rest API in Node.js. I have email id and user id in database. I want to share a file (present on same server) from one user to a particular user.
Can anyone tell me how this can be done in a best way ?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
const server = require('./../server/server.js')
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('../models/user.js');
let sockets = [];

    io.on('connection', socket=>{
    console.log("User connected");

    socket.on('online', (data)=>{
        socket.name = data._id;
        sockets[data._id] = socket.id;
        console.log("user is online")
    })

    socket.on('send_file', (data)=>{
        User.find({emailId: data},{emailId:0, password:0})
        .exec()
        .then(userid => {
            if(userid.length<1){
            console.log("No such user");
            }
            else{
                console.log(userid[0].id);
                socket.to(sockets[userid[0].id]).emit('hello', "HELLO");
            }
        })
        .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        console.log("User disconnected");
    })
    })

    module.exports = io;
    
    server.listen('8080', (err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("running on port 8080");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already configured the socketio and express sever properly with he mechanism to save the file path and file name in you database.

Try something like this (with socketio)

```
let sockets = [];

    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
      socket.on("online", data => {
        socket.name = data.username;
        sockets[data.username] = socket.id;
      });

      socket.on("send_file", function(data) {
        // your logic to retrieve the file path from you database in to the variable **filedata** 
        // let filedata = ................
        socket.to(sockets[data.user]).emit("file",filedata);
      });

      socket.on("disconnect", reason => {
        sockets.splice(sockets.findIndex(id => id === socket.id), 1);
      });

    });
```

in send_file event you will have receive the username from the sender inside the data object. The following code will be one which will help you to send file to selected user.

**socket.to(sockets[data.user]).emit("file",filedata);**

**Replying to your 1st comment**.

history.push() will not refresh the client since its a single page application. 
But when you refresh(from user **A** side) a new socket session will be created then the other user(user **B**) will still be referring the old socket session(which is already being disconnected by the refresh). So to handle this use the following lines

```
 socket.on("online", data => {
    socket.name = data.username;
    sockets[data.username] = socket.id;
  });
```

where you will be keeping a pool(an array) of `sockets` with the usernames so when ever a user refresh their client the newly created socket will be referring to the same user. Since you will be updating the the socket.id to the same person.
For example assume that you the user who refresh the client and im the other user. so when you refresh a new socket session will be created an it will be sent to the back end along with the user name. When the data comes to the server it will get your session object from the array(**sockets[data.username]**) and update it with the new socketio sent from your front-end **sockets[data.username] = socket.id;**.

for this to happen you will have to send the user name along with the socket message. like this

```
socket.emit("online", {
  username: "username"
});
```

**Replying to your 2nd comment**
To send data in real time the users should be online. if not you can just create an array of notifications with the following information (sender and receiver). So when the receiver logs in or clicks on the notification panel the list of shared files notification can be shown. This is just a suggestion you can come up with you own idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am new with socket.io. I established the socket on user login and it works fine on other links too like /dashboard, /dashboard/gdrive, but user gets disconnected when i refresh the page. I am using history.push to navigate to other pages.

Comment: and one more thing, I think according to your code it is necessary for both clients to be online to share the file but what i need is similar to friend requests in facebook i.e. receiver should be notified that "someone shared a file with you" , it doesn't matter whether the receiver is online or not.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried out. so i can look into it

Comment: @AnmolMiddha i updated the answer. Always remember to post you code and ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of non-realtime data:

**Server Side:** Use `res.sendFile()` is a way to solve this problem. In addition to the file send the receiver and sender ID in the headers.

**Client Side:** Increase the notification count if the receiver ID matches the logged-in user.

```
res.sendFile(path.join("path to file"), {
  headers: {
    receiverid:result[0]._id,
    senderid:result[1]._id
  }
});
```

In case of realtime data, follow the answer posted by TRomesh.